# NodeMCU socket client using Lua doesn't connect

Tags: node.js, lua, nodemcu

I want to connect a NodeMCU socket client to node.js socket server.
I'm using Lua programming language in NodeMCU.  I tried this code for the client but it didn't work.

```lua
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("SSID","Password")
wifi.sta.connect()
ip = wifi.sta.getip()
print("your IP is "..ip)

sk = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)

sk:on("receive", function ( sck,c )
  print (c)
end)

sk:on("connection", function ( sck,c )
  print("connected")
  sk:send("Helloooo...")
end)

sk:connect(3000,"192.168.1.4")
```

The node.js server code is tested and worked well.

```js
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone is connected');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the [NodeMCU fundamentals](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/#programming-model) wrong. NodeMCU is asynchronous and event-driven i.e. most calls are non-blocking.

That means that after you issue `wifi.sta.connect()` (which doesn't block) you need to wait until the device got an IP before you can continue. Here's an abbreviated [startup sequence from our docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua):

```lua
function startup()
    -- do stuff here
end

print("Connecting to WiFi access point...")
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(SSID, PASSWORD)
-- wifi.sta.connect() not necessary because config() uses auto-connect=true by default
tmr.alarm(1, 1000, 1, function()
    if wifi.sta.getip() == nil then
        print("Waiting for IP address...")
    else
        tmr.stop(1)
        print("WiFi connection established, IP address: " .. wifi.sta.getip())
        print("You have 3 seconds to abort")
        print("Waiting...")
        tmr.alarm(0, 3000, 0, startup)
    end
end)
```